# timezone convertion issue when system preferences and user preferences are different in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

date is not coming properly when my system preference  Asia/Kolkata,user preferences input date is America/Los_Angeles both are different

date is coming properly when my system preference & user preferences same

jsfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/uq99udc9/728/

```
//system preference Asia/Kolkata
// input date America/Los_Angeles --- 2016-11-09 02:00:00
var date = new Date("2016-11-09 02:00:00");
var gmtdate = date.toGMTString(); -- converting into GMT
$("#divThai").text(moment.tz(gmtdate,'Asia/Kolkata'));
$("#divUsa").text(moment.tz(gmtdate,'America/Los_Angeles'));
```

any one help me out from this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
// Parse the date in Los Angeles timezone.
const date = moment.tz('2016-11-09 02:00:00', 'America/Los_Angeles');
// Output the date.
console.log(date.toString());
// Output the date in Asia/Kolkata timezone.
console.log(date.tz('Asia/Kolkata').toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.9/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: const date = moment.tz('2016-11-09 02:00:00', 'America/Los_Angeles');

Comment: I want to save the date into milliseconds and again want to convert into different timezone like below

Comment: Wed Nov 09 2016 02:00:00 GMT-0800
Wed Nov 09 2016 15:30:00 GMT+0530

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: it's working for me but I want to store the miliiseconds instead of date in database

Comment: @mounish To get the milliseconds, call the `valueOf()` method, for example `date.valueOf()`.

Comment: I am facing one more issue when given 12 hours format through datetimepicker

Comment: var zoneFormatDate  = moment(inputdate).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a");

Comment: inputdate is 12 hours format like either 2016-11-21 10:30 am or 2016-11-21 02:20 pm

Comment: post converting also need to display which is given input date